# cannot find symbol method getArguments()

Tags: android

Is there any other way to call intent activity for my carousel? Here is my error:

> Error:(105, 39) error: cannot find symbol method getArguments()

I have added:

> final int pos   = this.getArguments().getInt("pos");

but it is showing me:

> error that cannot find symbol method getArguments()

Here is my code:

```
 package com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.fragment;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    //import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    //import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.R;
    import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.Registration;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    import in.goodiebag.carouselpicker.CarouselPicker;
    import technolifestyle.com.imageslider.FlipperLayout;
    import technolifestyle.com.imageslider.FlipperView;

    public class FragmentAction extends Fragment {

        CarouselPicker carouselPicker1;
        ViewPager viewPager;


        private static final String KEY_MOVIE_TITLE = "key_title";

        public FragmentAction() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        public static FragmentAction newInstance(String movieTitle) {
            FragmentAction fragmentAction = new FragmentAction();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(KEY_MOVIE_TITLE, movieTitle);
            fragmentAction.setArguments(args);

            return fragmentAction;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {


            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_action,container,false);
            TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.textView12 );
            txt.setText("\u25BA Creative & Dedicated Team");
            TextView txt1 = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.textView13 );
            txt1.setText("\u25BA Affordable Cost");
            TextView txt2 = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.textView14 );
            txt2.setText("\u25BA Maintain Long Relationship");
            TextView txt3 = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.textView15 );
            txt3.setText("\u25BA Timely Deliverly ");


            viewPager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
            ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( this.getContext() );
            viewPager.setAdapter( viewPagerAdapter );

            Timer timer = new Timer(  );
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new Mytime(),2000,4000 );


            CarouselPicker carouselPicker1 = (CarouselPicker)v.findViewById( R.id.carouselPicker1 );
            List<CarouselPicker.PickerItem> itemsImages = new ArrayList<>();

            itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.website_design));
            itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.digital_marketing));
            itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.domain_registration));
            itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.graphic));
            itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.mob));
            itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.server));
            itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.software_development));
            itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.ontent));
            itemsImages.add(new CarouselPicker.DrawableItem(R.drawable.ssl));
            carouselPicker1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final int pos   = this.getArguments().getInt("pos");
                    switch (pos)
                    {
                        case 0:  Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(getActivity(), website_designing.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity0);
                            break;
                        case 1:  Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(getActivity(), digital_marketing.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity1);
                            break;
                        case 2:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(getActivity(), DomainRegistration.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity2);
                            break;
                        case 3:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(getActivity(), GraphicDesign.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity3);
                            break;
                        case 4:  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(getActivity(), MobileApps.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity4);
                            break;
                        case 5:  Intent newActivity5 = new Intent(getActivity(), ServerHosting.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity5);
                            break;
                        case 6:  Intent newActivity6 = new Intent(getActivity(), SoftwareDevelopment.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity6);
                            break;
                        case 7:  Intent newActivity7 = new Intent(getActivity(), SoftwareDevelopment.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity7);
                            break;
                        case 8:  Intent newActivity8 = new Intent(getActivity(), SSL.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity8);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } );



    //        CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter imageAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this,itemsImages,0);
            CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter imageAdapter = new CarouselPicker.CarouselViewAdapter(this.getContext(),itemsImages,0);
            carouselPicker1.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

            FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton)v.findViewById( R.id.floatingActionButton );
            floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity( new Intent( getActivity(),Registration.class ) );
                }
            } );




    //        carouselPicker1.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    //            @Override
    //            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    //
    //            }
    //
    //
    //
    //            @Override
    //            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    //                if(position == 0){
    //                    startActivity(new    Intent(getActivity(), website_designing.class));
    //                }
    //                else if(position == 1){
    //                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), digital_marketing.class));
    //                }
    //                else if(position == 2){
    //                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), DomainRegistration.class));
    //                }
    //                else if(position == 3){
    //                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), GraphicDesign.class));
    //                }
    //                else if(position == 4){
    //                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MobileApps.class));
    //                }
    //                else if(position == 5){
    //                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ServerHosting.class));
    //                }
    //                else if(position == 6){
    //                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SoftwareDevelopment.class));
    //                }
    //                else if(position == 7){
    //                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ContentWriting.class));
    //                }
    //                else if(position == 8){
    //                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SSL.class));
    //                }
    //            }
    //
    //            @Override
    //            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    //
    //            }
    //        });


    //        ImageButton imageButton =(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.movie_icon);
    //        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //            @Override
    //            public void onClick(View v) {
    //                startActivity( new Intent( getActivity(), Registration.class ) );
    //            }
    //        });

            return v;

        }

        public class Mytime extends TimerTask{
            @Override
            public void run() {

                getActivity().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem( 1 );
                        }
                        else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem()== 1){
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem( 2 );

                        }
                        else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem()== 2){
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem( 3 );

                        }
                        else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem()== 3){
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem( 4 );

                        }
                        else {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        }
                    }
                } );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            Drawable movieIcon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.webdesign, getContext().getTheme());


            String movieTitle = getArguments().getString(KEY_MOVIE_TITLE);

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should move `this.getArguments()` out of  `onClick` as below

```
final int pos   = this.getArguments().getInt("pos");
 carouselPicker1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    switch (pos)
                    {
                        case 0:  Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(getActivity(), website_designing.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity0);
                            break;
                        case 1:  Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(getActivity(), digital_marketing.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity1);
                            break;
                        case 2:  Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(getActivity(), DomainRegistration.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity2);
                            break;
                        case 3:  Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(getActivity(), GraphicDesign.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity3);
                            break;
                        case 4:  Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(getActivity(), MobileApps.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity4);
                            break;
                        case 5:  Intent newActivity5 = new Intent(getActivity(), ServerHosting.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity5);
                            break;
                        case 6:  Intent newActivity6 = new Intent(getActivity(), SoftwareDevelopment.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity6);
                            break;
                        case 7:  Intent newActivity7 = new Intent(getActivity(), SoftwareDevelopment.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity7);
                            break;
                        case 8:  Intent newActivity8 = new Intent(getActivity(), SSL.class);
                            startActivity(newActivity8);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } );
```

because `this` not is instance of your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

use getArguments() without using this.

```
final int pos   = getArguments().getInt("pos");
```